# Angular - Get ng-repeat object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to get the current object out of an ng-repeat on ng-click, I can't use $index because I'm using orderBy and therefore it gives me the wrong index relative to the scope object. Idealy I want to be able to click on the object (thumbnail) and have $scope.activePerson gain all that objects values.

My data is structured as follows:

```
      [
        {
          'name': 'john'
        },
        {
          'name': 'toby'
        },
        {
          'name': 'sarah'
        }
      ]
```

This is very much simplified, my real objects have 30+ KV pairs and subobjects. There are 10 objects that I'm repeating from (in batches of 4).

My current HTML is:

```
.item.fourth(ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-name' " ng-show="$index <= 3" nid="{{person.guid}}"
```

Thanks

Comment: don't worry about the index....just pass the whole object into ng-click function. Also take a look at `limitTo: length:start` filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use orderBy and copy the current object from ng-repeat, [see this plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPwzeJ7iXcP1IRUB09BF) Relevant code:

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stuff = [
        {
          'name': 'john'
        },
        {
          'name': 'toby'
        },
        {
          'name': 'sarah'
        }
      ];

    $scope.setActivePerson = function (obj) {
      $scope.activePerson = obj;
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="thing in stuff | orderBy: 'name'">
      <input type="radio" ng-click="setActivePerson(thing)" />
      {{ thing.name }}
    </div>
    <br />
    <div ng-model="activePerson">Active: {{ activePerson.name }}</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This will not work, try selecting sarah, toby would be the active person instead.

Comment: You are correct, check the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UPwzeJ7iXcP1IRUB09BF

You just need to copy the person to activePerson.

Answer (score 3):

It's just `person` in `ng-repeat="person in people"`;

I'm not sure what kind of markdown you're using, you definitely don't have html there, but you want something like:

```
<div 
     ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-name' " 
     ng-show="$index <= 3" 
     nid="{{person.guid}}" 
     ng-click="activePerson = person">
</div>
```

Note that ng-repeat creates a child scope, so you'll want to have `activePerson` already set in the parent scope.

Comment: It was jade. Thanks, this is also a solution.